# Google Analytic Event tracking count fail

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I face a strange problem when I use event tracking to track a link. For example, I have a link

```
<a href="a.html" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'cool', 'Click', 'link1']);" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

The event tracker is working fine and in the google analytic dashboard I saw around 1500 clicks, but the pageview I get from `a.html` is around 600, the difference is 900, how could this happen? Both counts suppose to be similar.

Anyone have some suggestions?